# Does urlopen (request) follow all redirects by default?

Tags: python, http

Can someone confirm that http redirects are not enabled by default for `urllib.request.urlopen()`

I'm trying to trigger `urllib.request.urlopen(req)`. The response seen using my web browser Firefox (not python) is `HTTP 302` which indicates a redirect and then Firefox automatically goes to the redirected page which returns `HTTP 301 (permanently moved)` followed by `HTTP 200 (OK)`.

I'm simulating what the browser is doing in python but the resulting web page is not as expected and I believe it's because the redirect is not being handled.

Comment: had a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414563/how-to-check-if-the-urllib2-follow-a-redirect ?

Comment: Yes i read that post and I still I can't determine if using request.urlopen(req) would follow redirects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for confirmation.

Comment: I read it too and my view is: yes it does